# Is it possible to display incoming calls groupped by caller?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, lenovo

In  "all calls" i have something like this:

- John Doe 14:32
- Peter 14:30
- John Doe 14:25
- Peter 14:10

On another android device with same version i would have:

- John Doe (2) 14:32
- Peter (2) 14:30

Which is much, much better. But i could't figure out how to change that.

---

Model number: Lenovo K910
Android version: 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This greatly depends on the Dialer application you are using.  On stock "vanilla" Android that ships with Google/AOSP Dialer app, there is no such option, and you will have to find a 3rd-party dialer app that has such a feature (e.g. [Dialer One](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.dialer.DialerOne) or [PP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pixelrush.xphonefree), for example.)

Some manufacturers like Samsung and HTC replace the default dialer app with their own that has many more features, and may already include the one you are looking for (grouping records by caller.)

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your contacts by syncronizing all of them into your Google account. Once you do that you can organize them throught the Gmail page. Below of Google Logo there is a menu were you can choose **Contacts** There you can organize them in an easy way

[image]